# How to get available item quantity in picking ticket form in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

how to get available item quantity in picking ticket form in netsuite?

Thanks,
Shachi

Comment: what do you mean by `available item` ? Can you please elaborate your requirement.

Comment: are you using the basic forms or the advanced pdf/html forms?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using `item.onhand` as well if you are talking about total inventory available or `location.onhand` if you are talking about shipping from a certain location.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best off using the item.locationquantityavailable.
The difference in available vs. on hand is:

On hand is inventory that has yet to be shipped, but includes inventory in a picked fulfillment status, which may be allocated to other orders.

Available is inventory that is not allocated to other orders and not currently in a stage of fulfillment.

If you're using the advanced form, view source code and add element item.locationquantityavailable@label